# Which characters have appeared in every episode of Game Of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Are there any characters which have appeared in every episode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Zero**

As of 8/13/17 there are 65 aired episodes and the character who has appeared most is Tyrion, at 59 episodes.

It would be impossible therefore for someone to be in all episodes moving forward.

[image: imdbscreen]

(Screenshot courtesy of iOS IMDB app)

Comment: "As of 8/13/17 there are 73 episodes" - that is a little misleading... As I understand it that 73 episodes include the unaired episodes of season seven and eight but saying "as of 8/13/17" makes it sound like you are talking about aired episodes. Its also misleading in comparison to the number of episodes characters have been in from the screnshot since that number is presumably only counting the aired episodes that they have credits for (ie Tyrion is 59/65, not 59/73). The logic still holds since it is less than the 65 episodes they have credits for but I think you could do with being clearer

Comment: Fixed.    Good catch.